# FINDSTR to find text START END of string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I have string `photo="999" price="10" category="1"` . I want to get only `10`. This means I need to the string which start price=" and ends with "

```
@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%A In ('FindStr /I "^price=" "C:\price.txt" 2^>NUL')Do @Set "Ver=%%~B"
@Echo(%%Ver%% = %Ver% & Pause
```

Comment: Your `FindStr` match is not correct, because it is trying to match any line in `C:\price.txt` which begins with the string `price=`, and clearly your line begins with `photo=`. Even if you were to change it to `"^photo="`, your first token `%%A`, would resolve to `photo` and your second token, `%%B`, would resolve to `"999" price="10" category="1"`. In that case, you would therefore need to perform further actions on  `%%B` to isolate your required value.

Comment: What about `for /F "tokens=4 delims== " %%A in ("C:\price.txt") do echo/%%~I`?

Comment: Do you need to find ANY price? Then use this: `@For /F "Tokens=4 Delims=^= " %%A In ('TYPE "C:\price.txt" ^| FIND /I "price="""') Do @( Set "Ver=%%~A"& Echo Price found was "%%~A"` OR are you saying you only want price when it equals 10?  (seems less likely imo)  If so use this: `@For /F "Tokens=4 Delims=^= " %%A In ('TYPE "C:\price.txt" ^| FIND /I "price=""10"""') Do @( Set "Ver=%%~A")`  The way your question title and content is worded it's a little unclear what you really need to accomplish.  Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

`findstr` *always* returns the *complete line*, if successful. So it's not the right tool for this task (actually, there is no tool in `cmd` at all that could do that this way).

But with a bit of logic, you can work around it: remove the part from the start until (including) the triggerword `price` (a task, the `set` command is happy to do), then process the rest with a `for /f` loop to get the desired substring:

```
set "string=photo="999" price="10" category="1""
echo check: %string%
echo debug: %string:*price=%
for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%a in ("%string:*price=%") do set "ver=%%~a"
echo ver=%ver%
```

If you are sure of the exact format of your string (in your example the searched substring is the second quoted argument, so the fourth token when splitted by `"`) it gets as easy as:

```
for /f tokens^=4^ delims^=^" %%a in ("%string%") do echo ver=%%~a
```

or

```
for /f tokens^=4^ delims^=^" %%a in (file.txt) do echo ver=%%~a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which tries to follow a similar methodology as your example code.

It uses `FindStr` to isolate any line in `C:\price.txt`, which includes the word `price="<OneOrMoreDigits>"`. That line is saved as a variable named `price`, which is split under delayed expansion in a nested `For` loop, to remove everything up to, and including the first instance of the string  `price`, leaving, in this case, `="10" category="1"`. The nested loop further splits that, to take the second token, using a doublequote character as the delimiter, *(which should be your required value)*.

```bsh
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /IR "\<price=\"[0123456789]*\"\>" "C:\price.txt"') Do @(Set "price=%%G" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%H In ("!price:* price=!") Do @EndLocal & Set "price=%%H")
@Echo %%price%% = %price% & Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

set "string=photo="999" price="10" category="1""

:: remove quotes
set "string=%string:"=%"
for /f %%a in ("%string:* price=%") do set /a pricefound%%a
set pri
goto :eof
```

Since we don't have a representative sample of the file in question, we're forced to the conclusion that the requirement is to find the one and only appearance of  `price="anumber"` in the file.

So, since `findstr` output, properly framed, would select this line, all we need do is process the string.

This is kind of a quick-and-dirty method; it may be adequate for OP's purpose.

First, remove the quotes from the string as they have a habit of interfering.

Next, use `for /f` in string-processing mode where it does its magic on the quoted string in parentheses. The string is the original string, minus quotes, so replace all characters up to "<kbd>Space</kbd>price" with *nothing* and take the first token of the result, resulting in `=10` assigned to `%%a` in the example case.

Then execute "set /a somevariablename`=10`" by simply concatenating the two strings.

Note that if the file contains a line like `... pricelastweek="9" ...` then other measures may need to be taken.

Answer (score 0):

Well clearly you need to match lines that contain `price="` as there may be other lines.

What's unclear is if you need match `10` exactly, or just want that to be any number.

It seems likely you just want to match any number and grab it.

This is done easily with:

```cmd
@For /F "Tokens=4 Delims=^= " %%A In ('
  TYPE "C:\price.txt" ^| FIND /I "price="""') Do @(
    Set "Ver=%%~A" & CALL SET Ver &Pause )
```

While is you need to match `Price="10"`, which seems less useful, but at least one person took that meaning and your wording is a little unclear so I will add that was well:

```cmd
@For /F "Tokens=4 Delims=^= " %%A In ('
  TYPE "C:\price.txt" ^| FIND /I "price=""10"""') Do @(
    Set "Ver=%%~A" & CALL SET Ver &Pause )
```

Note in all examples I left in the `@` symbols since I assume this is you being clever, and leaving `ECHO ON` and only removing the `@` symbols when you want to debug some specific thing you are doing.

However, in case not, it's worth pointing out that in a script it's usually easiest to place `ECHO OFF` at the start of the script instead of putting an `@` at the beginning of each statement to stop it from echoing.

Cheers! :)

Comment: Ben, could you please state which "`person took that meaning`" "`need to match Price="10"`"?

Comment: @compo Perhaps!  Can you keep a secret?

Comment: I have no idea, nobody has ever entrusted me with one!